# Indexer stuck in processing

Tags: magento2, indexing, reindex

Magento ver. 2.0.7

Hello, I'm trying to reindex my store so that products I added from the backend will show up on the frontend.

As shown below, after running `bin/magento indexer:reindex`, every index has been rebuilt successfully but `bin/magento indexer:status` shows some of the indices still processing as confirmed in the `Admin Panel > System > Index Management`

What can I do to resolve this? My website no longer shows any products.

```
[user@server root]$ bin/magento indexer:reindex
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00

[user@server root]$ bin/magento indexer:status
Customer Grid:                                     Processing
Category Products:                                 Processing
Product Categories:                                Processing
Product Price:                                     Ready
Product EAV:                                       Ready
Stock:                                             Ready
Catalog Rule Product:                              Ready
Catalog Product Rule:                              Ready
Catalog Search:                                    Processing
```

[image: Index Management]

Comment: You can run `php bin/magento indexer:reset` to reset the ones stuck on 'processing', then reindex them all (again). That probably won't solve your real problem though.

Comment: Try reindexing only one of the problematic ones and see if errors display.

Comment: @RyanH. I'm getting an err msg 'Command "indexer:reset" is not defined'

Comment: @SteveJohnson They're still stuck in processing, let's see what Magento forums say

Answer (score 17):

You can fix this from the command line by reseting the index which will invalidate the state of the index and remove the processing flag from the index.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Optionally you may also append the index name to the command to just just reset that index.

Comment: This command doesn't exist in 2.0.4

Comment: but answer is absolutly right its work for me thanks in 2.1.6

Comment: @jtate then your only options is to upgrade magento

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately your only option is to change in the database the state of the processing indexes because till there are processing indexes no other index gets updated and neither the command line works.

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where indexer_id = 'catalogsearch_fulltext';
```

also keep in mind this bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5146 that might be the cause for your problem

Comment: This is not the only option, index state can be reset from the m2 cli which is more satisfactory than tinkering with tables.

Comment: no, it can't. try and you'll see. but i agree with you, would be best if it worked from cli

Comment: With indexer:reset (not indexer:reindex)? Works fine for me. I can cause the error situation that causes the reindex to fail and am able to recover to the state of invalidated. I can then re-run the reindex (which without the command would have just been skipped as it was marked as processing) in a situation it will not error and all is fine.

Comment: my bad, i didn't know about indexer:reset. i'll check that out, thanks in case it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this issue and it turned out that it was because the "innodb_buffer_pool_size" mysql size was not big enought (we had too many comples sales_rules).

Comment: solution of this problem?

Comment: @Hiren, it is obvious, just make innodb_buffer_pool_size bigger.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 indexer states are stored in `indexer_state` table.

In case in the CLI reset does not work, change the state directly from the table.

If Product Price is stuck for long time, use following. And so on.

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where indexer_id = 'catalog_product_price';
```